# Adding two binary strings

Tags: c++, binary, addition

How does code block in while loop execute?

```
 string addBinary(string a, string b)
    {
        string s = "";

        int c = 0, i = a.size() - 1, j = b.size() - 1;
        while(i >= 0 || j >= 0 || c == 1)
        {
            c += i >= 0 ? a[i --] - '0' : 0;
            c += j >= 0 ? b[j --] - '0' : 0;
            s = char(c % 2 + '0') + s;
            c /= 2;
        }

        return s;
    }
```

Also here `c` is `int` type, then what does `c%2+'0'` and any char `a[i]-'0'` mean?

Comment: c % 2 stands for c modulo 2; '0' is the character 0 in ascii, ans thus '0' + 1 is '1' in ascii; a[i] - '0' is probably to get the integral value represented by the character in a[i]

Comment: What is a binary string?

Comment: your title `Adding two binary strings` doesn't give overview of what you're asking for

Comment: @eerorika string made of only 0's and 1's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr it's using ASCII arithmetic to translate characters into numbers for use in binary arithmetic.

Binary addition is the addition of two binary numbers - this code is taking advantage of how C++ casts `char` to `int` in order to facilitate this. The [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for a number is how it's represented behind-the-scenes; for example, `'0'` corresponds to 48 and `'1'` corresponds to 49. The C++ function `'1' - '0'` is actually returning `49 - 48`; it subtracts the ascii code values. That's why, for example `'a' - '0'` return `49`: the code for `'a'` is 97, and 97 - 48 = 49.

**`a[i] - '0'` is an extension of this,** taking the character in question and "subtracting" the ASCII value of `'0'` from it. If the character in `a[i]` is a `'0'`, this is 48 - 48; if it's a `'1'`, it's 49 - 48. The result is a numeral 0 or 1, respectively, which can be used for the binary arithmetic.

Using the above logic, the code is starting at the right-hand side of the two input strings and parsing the characters one letter at a time, using these properties to determine if the current letter is a `'0'` or a `'1'`, and then putting the result into `c`. (If you're doing this yourself, you can also cast the character to int as with `(int)a[i--]` if you want, but this will fail if you give it bad input.)

The int variable `c` is receiving a 1 if the current digit in the first string is a `'1'` and a 0 if it's a `'0'`. If both of the characters are `'1'`s, then `c` becomes 2; this is means we need to "carry" the bit. The carry is facilitated by `c /= 2;`: since `int`s don't round when they're divided, if `c` is 0 or 1, it will be 0 in the next iteration, whereas if it's 2, it'll be 1 in the next iteration.

**`c % s + '0'` is converting the number back** into a `char` to be added to the string. It takes the ASCII code for `'0'` (48) and either adds 0 to it if `c` is 0 or 2 (leaving it as 48, or `'0'`) or adds 1 to it if `c` is 1 (changing it to 49, or `'1'`). As an interesting note, if you add enough to `'0'`, it'll eventually go into the letters, and then symbols, and some other unprintable ASCII characters.

Once you've got the ASCII logic and are ready to tackle the binary logic, [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-add-two-binary-strings/) includes a [video explaining the code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TraAvM7JxL4). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Any digit represented as character if you subtract from char '0', you will get its numerical value. e.g. '2' -'0' = 2

C%2 - will get you the remainder 0 or 1 and then adding '0' to convert it into character 
i.e. from '1' (char)  to 1 (integer)

Comment: But compiler is giving for 2-'0' =-46.

Comment: you have to do '2' - '0'  that will give you 2 both characters  . .What you are doing is 2(int) - '0' (char ascii 48) so getting -46

Comment: @PraveenB Thanks